# Create a tab indicator for a stack of fragments

Tags: android

I have an activity, and a bunch of fragments in it. The fragments are not transitioned by sliding, but by button click. I'm trying to build a tab indicator like the one in the bottom that shows which fragment the user is. I don't even know how it's called.

This is my main Activity where all the fragments belong, and with the actionbar menu the user navigates throught the fragments. In the activity it's switched straight to the first fragment out of 4 fragments (DetailsFragment)

```
public class CreateWorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_workout);

    DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.create_activity_frameLayout, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

            if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                fm.popBackStack();
            }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWw8D.png)

Comment: Could you add some code to this question? Also please ask just one question at a time.

Comment: Added my activity, sorry.

Comment: Have a look at this repo [Android Tab and Fragment](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)

Answer (score 0):

as i cannot see your code, I have this to offer https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter ... refer this

Comment: VIewPager class is responsible for sliding possible.

Comment: The viewPager is used for sliding, I don't want the fragments to be slided, but just show the indicator of the fragments.